# Struts 2: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: java, session, tomcat, struts2, interceptor

I need your help.
The problem is:

1. tomcat destroy the session after time in `<session-timeout>` is over
2. user click on link within app
3. we get error:

> ```
>  java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:407)
>   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:725)
>   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
>   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:617)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1760)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```

Like it works internally:
Error can be reproduced only for some actions.
for example this url reproduce issue

```
localhost:8080/myapp/editPromotion?promoId=TestBes
```

and this one is not

```
localhost:8080/myapp/searchCustomerHome
```

the interceptor works the same for these urls

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    if (!isLoginAction(invocation)) {
        Map<String, Object> sessionMap = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

        if (sessionMap.get(LoginAction.USER_NAME) == null) {
            return "notAuthenticated";
        }
    }

    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

and return "notAuthenticated".

Also I have in struts.xml this piece of code:

```
    <global-results>
         <result name="notAuthenticated" type="redirect">login</result>
    </global-results>
```

The only difference error request goes to

org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MessageStoreInterceptor.java

and starts running

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    LOG.debug("entering MessageStoreInterceptor ...");

    before(invocation);
    String result = invocation.invoke();
    after(invocation, result);

    LOG.debug("exit executing MessageStoreInterceptor");
    return result;
}
```

I have no idea why they works so different.

Comment: Is this all stacktrace?

Comment: yes, it's a stacktrace from tomcat.
the internal error that a found during debugging is

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Comment: What a version of struts? Post a full list of library set. Did you set `devMode`? What is the output on the console or server logs?

Comment: What is your struts configuration `struts.xml`, what is your descriptor `web.xml`?

Comment: no, devMode is false.
version of struts is 2.

list if libraries:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a0kd7uy835qmszg/myapp-libs.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p658wogcxxaa5s1/web.xml

Comment: 2 is a major version, what is the minor version and effective major and minor versions?

Comment: Your library set is a mix of different versions of Struts2, you need upgrade to the latest version of Struts2. Remove unused or renamed jars.

Comment: thanks for your help Roman.

Actually I found out the root cause of the issue:<br/>
In action description was used the interceptor
<pre>
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
<code>
<br/>
and this interceptor trying to store some data to the session.

Comment: it looked like this:
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultInterceptorStack" />

and the problem was the authenticate interceptor runs AFTER interceptor that tries to save some data to the session.

It should be like this
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultInterceptorStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>

Comment: You could post this as an answer, really I thought it were another problems. But you didn't even post `struts.xml` I've asked above, so I was unable to help.

Comment: In any case, Roman, thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - everything was fine until the session timed out then, depending on which action was requested I would see this exception.

I solved the problem by adding the "createSession" interceptor as the first interceptor in the action and it solved the problem.